# firewalld command alternative of iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, iptables, firewalld

firewalld command alternative of `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`
I have to run `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` in order to run kubernetes cluster and communicate from pods using the service name.

Problem is that I have k8s cluster running on centos7 and using firewalld instead of iptables and that is default in cenots, without iptables service running i can't save rule `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` and that take effect after  reboot, if can get firwalld alternative of `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` then I can persist it easily on reboot.

Comment: how many nodes do you have?

Comment: 3 nodes, 1 master and 2 worker nodes

Answer (score 1):

sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter FORWARD 0 -d 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT
sudo firewall-cmd --reload